# clave primaria y foranea MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Mi pregunta es acerca de: Puede una clave primaria estar asociada a dos o mas claves foraneas?
'''MySql
int primary key

Comment: Dos llaves foráneas que estén en una tabla o dos llaves foráneas en 2 tablas distintas?

Comment: cerian 5 claves foraneas en la misma tabla

Comment: **hasta donde conozco no**, una llave primaria solo debe estar asociada a una llave foránea y no a mas, aquí en la doc, de SQL Server describen mejor las características que deben poseer ambas: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints?view=sql-server-2017#FKeys

Comment: joya muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Sí, una clave principal puede contener todos los campos que necesites, tengan claves foráneas o no:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE personas(
  id_persona int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  persona varchar(31)
  );

CREATE TABLE destinos(
  id_destino int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  destino varchar(31)
  );

CREATE TABLE visitan(
  id_persona int NOT NULL,
  id_destino int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_persona) REFERENCES personas(id_persona),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_destino) REFERENCES destinos(id_destino),
  PRIMARY KEY(id_persona,id_destino)
  );
```

Si tienes dificultades para diferenciar INDEX, PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, NOT NULL o FOREIGN KEY, indícamelo para ampliar la respuesta.

Comment: En el ejemplo que mencionas no es necesario utilizar __ON DELETE NO ACTION__, ni 
__ON UPDATE NO ACTION__ ?

Comment: Creo que, por defecto, asume un `ON DELETE RESTRICT`. Es decir, que no te deja borrar un registro si hay otro que dependa de éste. La otra opción es `CASCADE` que elimina ambos. Que no haga nada no me parece que sea posible...